One electron orbiting two protons ($H_{2}^{+}$)

When there's one electron attracted by two protons, (in a two dimensional plane), the Hamiltonian of the electron is $$H=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \textbf{r}^{2}}-\frac{e^{2}}{|r_1|}-\frac{e^{2}}{|r_2|}.$$ The two lowest states of electron are $\Phi_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}[\phi(\textbf{r}_{1}) \pm \phi(\textbf{r}_{2})]$, where $\phi(\textbf{r})$  has the form of the wavefunction of the ground state hydrogen atom.
It seems like these two lowest states pop out just because of the superposition. If these two states are the two eigenstates of the Hamiltonian proposed above, the Hamiltonian can be transformed into $H=-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \textbf{r}_{1}^{2}}-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \textbf{r}_{2}^{2}}-\frac{e^{2}}{|r_1|}-\frac{e^{2}}{|r_2|}$ by some coordinate transformation.
Is this true? Or can you tell me what the transformed Hamiltonian (coordinate $r_1$, $r_2$) is?

Those are not actual eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. The Hamiltonian also cannot be transformed into the form you describe. And here's the kicker - even if the Hamiltonian could be transformed in that way, your proposed "two lowest states" would still not be eigenstates of your new Hamiltonian (hint $\partial r_1/\partial r_2\neq 0$). I don't really have time to write an answer with a proof of these statements. But I would say quantum mechanics is more complicated than you seem to think it might be.

@AXensen I agree that the hamiltonian can't be transformed into the one I proposed. Sorry for being stupid last night. But as it's said, these two states are the two lowest states of electron, doesn't it mean they should be the eigenstates of the electron hamiltonian that correspond to the two lowest energy? Could you point out from what form of hamiltonian can I see these two lowest eigenstates?

You are misreading your undisclosed text on the celebrated Hydrogen cation, $H_2^+$. The ground state wavefunction $\Phi_{\pm}$ is not exact, but approximate/variational, and serves to find the equilibrium R minimizing the total energy/force, utilizing the quantum virial theorem. Read up on  §40, §41 of J Frenkel's classic Wave mechanics: Elementary theory .

Slater 1934 for an overview of the method.

@CosmasZachos You're right, of course. I'm not sure a 90 year old paper will be useful to read (different nomenclature, different notation, etc.). Here's a phys libre article about this exact situation, where this exact variational wavefunction is used to estimate the ground state energy of H2+. they state clearly that this is a variational wavefunction. It is not a genuine eigenstate.
https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Introductory_Quantum_Mechanics_(Fitzpatrick)/13%3A_Variational_Methods/13.03%3A_Hydrogen_Molecule_Ion

@CosmasZachos  Thanks mates! Now I see the bug in my mind, the website link you shared is really useful.

Your notation r$_1$ and r$_2$ etc is confusing, both are just r minus a constant and the derivatives are identical. The physical reason why the decomposition makes no sense is that it ignores that both part of the wave function feel both potentials. This is the very reason why chemical bonds exist.
